# HTML5 input type number decimalpoint localization

Tags: html, forms, input

I would like to localize html5 number input field:

```
<input type="number">
```

In some countries the decimal point is not a dot, how can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on user's Operation system localization configuration or browser localization support or maybe both, i'm not sure exactly, for example my MS windows localization config. is set to `Persian-Iran` , it auto-coverts decimal points when i add `lang="fa-IR"` attribute to `<html>`

```
<html lang="fa-IR" dir="rtl">

    <body>
        <input type="number" step="0.2">
    </body>
</html>
```

Sample screen-shot :

[image: Localized Input type number example]